# svn copy on a subset of a directory

Tags: svn

I have a directory in svn which has about 30 files. I want to copy 4 of those to another directory in svn, so that I have traceability.

Is there a way that I can do this? or do I lose traceability?

The only way I could think of is to copy the whole directory, and remove all the files I don't need.

**clarification:**

Use case:

The root of the server is `http://someserver/svn`.

I have `http://someserver/svn/tools/foo/trunk` checked out locally.

There is also a `http://someserver/svn/tools/bar/trunk`.

I want to copy 4 files 
  from `http://someserver/svn/tools/foo/trunk/widgets/baz` to `http://someserver/svn/tools/foo/trunk/widgets/quux`.

Comment: simple 'svn cp file1 file2 file3' <dst_path>' should work for you. Am I missing some thing?

Answer (score 2):

Just use svn cp

```
svn cp file1 file2 file3 file4 ../otherDir/
```

Then commit.  You'll get to keep your history that way.

Comment: Separate branches or separate repository?

Comment: same repository, separate branches (not branches in the sense of development forking, but as in separate branches of the repository tree), where branch B is not part of the partial checkout of branch A.